# UTF8 to CP1255 conversion

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I am trying to convert a UTF-8 string to CP1255 (Hebrew)

I have tried running the following (I'm using detect_encoding because some of my inputs are not UTF-8):

```
foreach($param as $key=>$value){
    $newval = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($value),"cp1255",$value);
    $querystr .= $key."=".$newval."&";
}
```

Anyway, the result is that all the Hebrew characters returns the nice � symbol,
And all others(English/numbers) are as expected and wanted remain intact.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Exactly where do you _see_ the � symbols? Have you (double-/tripple-) checked that this medium is aware of the cp1255 encoding? E.g. in a browser check the page properties to see if it really switched to Hebrew.

Comment: on the chrome console -> network -> response tab(using ajax) also tried running mb_detect_encoding on the results and got "UTF-8"

Comment: oh, ajax... in that case why not stick with utf-8? If you take a look at the W3C specs of XMLHttpRequest et al you will find "use utf-8", "always utf-8", "strongly encouraged to use utf-8" all over the place.

Comment: i need to post the data to a different server that only accepts CP1255 encoding

Comment: Is it the client/browser that actually posts the data to the second server? If it is and you are using a `<form>` element stay with the utf-8 encoding on your first server and make it a `<form action="//secondserver..." accept-charset="windows-1255">` element to indicate to the browser that the enconding should be cp1255. see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset

Comment: im using CURL for transmitting the data to the server. Basically there is no client side evolved here at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
foreach($param as $key=>$value){
    $value_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value);
    if($value_encoding == "UTF-8"){
        $newval = iconv($value_encoding,"cp1255",$value);
    }else{
        $newval = $value;
    }
    $endpoint = add_query_arg($key,$newval,$endpoint);
}

$content = file_get_contents($endpoint);
```

Comment: mb_detect_encoding itself is already not 100% reliable, doing it on each parameter separately does not make much sense